# Track a history of request URLs in SPRING Based Web application(s)

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, web-applications, web, multi-tenant

I am working on a personal project, where i a front facing server that accepts requests validates them and then transfers the request to other applications.

The problem is when ever i have to track the previous flow i am dependent on the request parameters, since the requests are diverted to different applications based on the flow.

I came up with an idea create an API that maintains the STACK of request URLs and there parameters and make it available to all the applications.

PROBLEM: Since all the requests are mapped to the respective application through the front facing server, thought to add a header with string of previous requests and the APIs in applications will read the header to understand the previous flow.

BUT the size of the headers are limited, hence i cannot go with this approach, if i cannot use COOKIES to to the same process,

QUESTION

ARE there any APIs to keep track of the requests in STACK? If not then let me know a viable solution

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect opportunity for a filter!

```
@Component
public class RequestTrackingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest request,
        ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) {

        // Record the context this request was fired on.
        myDatabase.save(request.getServletContext());

        // Go along your merry way.
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I don't know if the `getServletContext()` method is the right one for you, but that request object knows a lot about which URL it was fired towards.

This filter can be configured for use either in your deployment descriptor, or if you have something that post-processes the filter chain (like Spring Security), you can just pin it at the end of the filter chain there. Just make sure requests from all contexts get fired at the filter by setting its mapping correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
How about this:

a) Create a Map where key will be the uri and value will be another Map. In the another Map the key will be request parameter name and value will be its value as below:

Map<String, Map<String, Object>> uriRequestInfo = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>();

For each uri do as below:

Map<String, Object> uriRequestParams = uriRequestInfo.get(uri);
if(uriRequestInfo == null) {
   uriRequestParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}

// Consider you have two parameters and values in request uri /pqr/xyz/abc.do as ?name=ganesh&age=12

uriRequestParams.put("name", "ganesh");
```